# Select oracle with if checking for result is 0 and return 0.5

Tags: sql, oracle

am really confused how i can get the following result with the following query i have.
When  `(LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM)` computes to 0 i want to put 0.5 as result and if it is null i want to place 0 as result , otherwise i want to use the exact difference returned form the (LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM).

Please,help

```
    INSERT INTO LEAVE_TAKEN_COUNT (NUMDAYS,EMPLOYEE_SERIAL_ID)
    SELECT NVL((LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM), 0) as NumDays , T.ID
    FROM TBL_EMPLOYEE T 
    LEFT JOIN TBL_LEAVE_REQUEST LR on T.ID = LR.EMPLOYEE_SERIAL_ID
    WHERE T.DATE_PERMANENT IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY T.ID;
```

Comment: Use `CASE` statement. `case LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM = 0 then 0.5 else LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CASE:

```
INSERT INTO LEAVE_TAKEN_COUNT (NUMDAYS,EMPLOYEE_SERIAL_ID)
    SELECT CASE WHEN LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM = 0 THEN 0.5
                WHEN (LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM) IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM
            END as NumDays , T.ID
    FROM TBL_EMPLOYEE T 
    LEFT JOIN TBL_LEAVE_REQUEST LR on T.ID = LR.EMPLOYEE_SERIAL_ID
    WHERE T.DATE_PERMANENT IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY T.ID;
```

Comment: brilliant answer Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LR.DATE_TO IS NULL OR LR.DATE_FROM IS NULL THEN 0
             WHEN LR.DATE_TO = LR.DATE_FROM THEN 0.5
             ELSE LR.DATE_TO - LR.DATE_FROM
        END) as NumDays, . . .
```